# how to pass printeventargs object of asp.net to javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web, printing

I am trying to optimize the code and do some changes to the old existing code. I have to implement print bill from the server side to the client side I try too many ways but I did not find any of one this is my code

```
 public void Print()
        {
            var doc = new PrintDocument();
            string pkInstalledPrinters = string.Empty; +
            //var doc = new PrintDocument();
            for (int i = 0; i < PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Count;)
            {
                pkInstalledPrinters = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters[i];
                break;
                //comboInstalledPrinters.Items.Add(pkInstalledPrinters); 
            }
            // doc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "\\\\W95053\\P12562PCL";
            doc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = pkInstalledPrinters;
            doc.PrinterSettings.Copies = 2;
            doc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(ProvideContent);
            doc.Print();
            doc.Print();
```

this is server-side code for printing

```
       public void ProvideContent(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime koDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-320);
            string totalAmount = TotalAmount.Value;
            //e.Graphics.DrawString("7 Plates Restaurant", new Font("Arial", 12), Brushes.Black, 50, 0);
            //e.Graphics.DrawString("Item", new Font("Arial", 11), Brushes.Black, 15, 30);
            //e.Graphics.DrawString("Qty", new Font("Arial", 11), Brushes.Black, 150, 30);
            //e.Graphics.DrawString("Rate", new Font("Arial", 11), Brushes.Black, 185, 30);
            string addressLine1 = hotel.Address;
            string addressLine2 = "Bangalore 560046";
            string phoneNo = "PH – " + hotel.PhoneNo;
            string date = koDate.Date.ToShortDateString();
            string tin = "29061276984";
            string time = koDate.ToShortTimeString();
            string cashier = "Sameer";
            e.Graphics.DrawString("7 Plates", new Font("Cambria", 24, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 60, 0);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Restaurant", new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 90, 40);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(addressLine1, new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 10, 60);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(addressLine2, new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 65, 75);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(phoneNo, new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 20, 90);
            // e.Graphics.DrawString(webSite, new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 70, 90);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Order No: " + orderNumber, new Font("Cambria", 11, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 0, 110);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Bill No: " + billNumber, new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 170, 110);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Date: " + date, new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 0, 125);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Time: " + time, new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 170, 125);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Tin: " + tin, new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 0, 140);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("No.", new Font("Cambria", 11, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 0, 160);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Item", new Font("Cambria", 11, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 25, 160);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Qty", new Font("Cambria", 11, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 140, 160);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Rate", new Font("Cambria", 11, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 175, 160);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Total", new Font("Cambria", 11, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 220, 160);

            int xAxis = 0;
            int yAxis = 180;
            int itemNo = 0;
            int totalValue = 0;
            foreach (DayEntryHR item in dayEntryList)
            {
                itemNo++;
                string no = Convert.ToString(itemNo) + ".";
                string itemName = item.MasterItem.Item;
                int rateMaster = item.MasterItem.KORate;
                double rate1 = Convert.ToInt32(rateMaster / 1.12) + 1;
                string rate = Convert.ToString(rate1);
                string total = Convert.ToString(rate1 * item.Quantity);
                string quantity = Convert.ToString(item.Quantity);
                totalValue = totalValue + Convert.ToInt32(total);
                //e.Graphics.DrawString(
                //  "Hello world",
                //  new Font("Arial", 12),
                //  Brushes.Black,
                //  e.MarginBounds.Left,
                //  e.MarginBounds.Top);

                e.Graphics.DrawString(no, new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, xAxis, yAxis);
                xAxis = xAxis + 25;
                e.Graphics.DrawString(itemName, new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, xAxis, yAxis);
                xAxis = xAxis + 120;
                e.Graphics.DrawString(quantity, new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, xAxis, yAxis);
                xAxis = xAxis + 30;
                e.Graphics.DrawString(rate, new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, xAxis, yAxis);
                xAxis = xAxis + 50;
                e.Graphics.DrawString(total, new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, xAxis, yAxis);
                xAxis = 0;
                yAxis = yAxis + 15;
                //e.Graphics.DrawString("2.", new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 0, 195);
                //e.Graphics.DrawString(c, new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 25, 195);
                //e.Graphics.DrawString("2", new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 145, 195);
                //e.Graphics.DrawString("150", new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 175, 195);
                //e.Graphics.DrawString("150", new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 225, 195);
                //e.Graphics.DrawString("3.", new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 0, 210);
                //e.Graphics.DrawString(d, new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 25, 210);
                //e.Graphics.DrawString("5", new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 145, 210);
                //e.Graphics.DrawString("150", new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 175, 210);
                //e.Graphics.DrawString("300", new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 225, 210);
                //e.Graphics.DrawString("4.", new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 0, 225);
                //e.Graphics.DrawString(f, new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 25, 225);
                //e.Graphics.DrawString("2", new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 145, 225);
                //e.Graphics.DrawString("110", new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 175, 225);
                //e.Graphics.DrawString("220", new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 225, 225);
            }

            int vat = ((totalValue * 12) / 100);
            //e.Graphics.DrawString("Vat 5.5%:", new Font("Cambria", 11, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 140, yAxis + 5);
            //e.Graphics.DrawString(Convert.ToString(Vat), new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 220, yAxis + 5);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Total:", new Font("Cambria", 11, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 140, yAxis + 5);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Convert.ToString(totalValue), new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 220, yAxis + 5);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Pay By: Cash", new Font("Cambria", 11, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 140, yAxis + 23);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("To provide feedback call us", new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 35, yAxis + 40);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Or", new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 100, yAxis + 55);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Visit us on www.7plates.in", new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 37, yAxis + 70);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Thank You", new Font("Cambria", 14, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 75, yAxis + 90);

            string name = Customer.Value + " " + LastName.Value;
            bool flag = false;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(name, new Font("Cambria", 14), Brushes.Black, 75, yAxis + 110);
            if (Homedelevery.Checked == true)
            {

                string addressline1 = string.Empty;
                string addressline2 = string.Empty;

                string address = Address.Value;
                if (address.Length > 28)
                {
                    addressline1 = address.Substring(0, 28);
                    addressline2 = address.Substring(28);
                    flag = true;
                }
                e.Graphics.DrawString("Address:", new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 0, yAxis + 140);
                if (flag == true)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(addressline1, new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 63, yAxis + 140);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(addressline2, new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 63, yAxis + 160);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("LandMark:", new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 0, yAxis + 180);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(Landmark.Value, new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 70, yAxis + 180);
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(address, new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 63, yAxis + 140);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("LandMark:", new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 0, yAxis + 160);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(Landmark.Value, new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 73, yAxis + 160);
                }
            }
            if (Takeaway.Checked == true)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString("Phone:", new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 0, yAxis + 140);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(Phone1.Value, new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 50, yAxis + 140);
                e.Graphics.DrawString("TakeAway", new Font("Cambria", 14, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 73, yAxis + 160);
            }
            else if (Homedelevery.Checked == true)
            {
                if (flag == true)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("Phone:", new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 0, yAxis + 200);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(Phone1.Value, new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 50, yAxis + 200);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("Home Delevery", new Font("Cambria", 14, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 70, yAxis + 220);
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("Phone:", new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 0, yAxis + 180);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(Phone1.Value, new Font("Cambria", 11), Brushes.Black, 50, yAxis + 180);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("Home Delevery", new Font("Cambria", 14, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 70, yAxis + 200);
                }
            }

            Pen myPen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Black, 1);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(myPen, 0, 176, 260, 176);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(myPen, 0, yAxis + 5, 260, yAxis + 5);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(myPen, 0, yAxis + 21, 260, yAxis + 21);

            //e.Graphics.DrawString(no, new Font("Arial", 10), Brushes.Black, xAxis, yAxis);
            //xAxis = xAxis + 15;
            //e.Graphics.DrawString(itemName, new Font("Arial", 10), Brushes.Black, xAxis, yAxis);
            //xAxis = xAxis + 145;
            //e.Graphics.DrawString(quantity, new Font("Arial", 10), Brushes.Black, xAxis, yAxis);
            //xAxis = xAxis + 30;
            //e.Graphics.DrawString(rate, new Font("Arial", 10), Brushes.Black, xAxis, yAxis);
            //yAxis = yAxis + 20;
            //xAxis = 0;

        }
```

I search a lot of stuff and I am trying to do this but I could not pass the object that I want to print

```
 protected void Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var doc = new PrintDocument();
            doc.PrinterSettings.Copies = 2;
            doc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(ProvideContent);

            //String msg = "alert('" + doc + "button)'";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", string.Format(@"
                                                                                           alert('u r inside a fucntion');
                                                    var prtwin = window.open('', 'PrintGridViewData', 'left=100,top=100,width=1000,height=100,tollbar=0,scrollbars=1,status=0,resizable=1');
                                                    prtwin.document.write('hello wolrd sjks');
                                                    prtwin.document.close();
                                                    prtwin.focus();
                                                    prtwin.print();
                                                    prtwin.close(); "
                                                , new PrintPageEventHandler(ProvideContent)), true);
            //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('heelo world');", true);
        }
```

thanks to read this long question

Comment: If you're trying to print to a printer connected to the client from code running on the server, you're out of luck. You would have to print from Javascript, and that gives you virtually no control - you can call [the `window.print` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print) to print the content of the current document, and that's it.

Comment: No I am trying to pass that printpageventargs object to javascript and then I can print with javascript. do u know any method that printpageeventargs object passing into javascript window.write the function as an argument

Comment: You *cannot* control printing from Javascript! All you can do is call `window.print()`; you have no control over the printer settings, and you cannot generate content other than what's in the page.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer whenever u use a print object in javascript **it read like HTML page **`window.print();` take the whole page and print but when u

u can see i write a text in below print function we can write and format like html page or we can create an html page and pass and then print that html page print
`prtwin.document.write('hello wolrd sjks')`